# How to query for a field that 'has only' clause?

Tags: sql

I am trying to query the following dataset:

```
Customer ID     Item Purchased
1234            Bread
1235            Peanut Butter
1234            Jelly
1234            Peanut Butter
1234            Jelly
5555            Peanut Butter
5555            Peanut Butter
1235            Jelly
```

I'm trying to get the expected result of:

```
Customer ID     Item Purchased
5555            Peanut Butter
```

In this case I want customer 5555 that's only purchased peanut butter and nothing else.

Comment: thanks Yogesh! do you know how to update the table

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using it tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.Customer = t.Customer and 
                        t1.Item <> 'Peanut Butter'
                 );
```

You can also simplify it using `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select Customer 
from table t
where Item = 'Peanut Butter'
group by Customer 
having min(Item) = max(Item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`customer_id`) FROM `tablename` WHERE
`customer_id` IN(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`items_purchased`)) AS `c`, 
`customer_id` FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `customer_id`) 
AND `items_purchased` = 'PEANUT BUTTER'
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation so OP can understand batter .